# How can I go about avoiding verification for a TikTok bot with proxies?

Tags: screen-scraping, proxies, tiktok

I am making a TikTok bot for fun. It does not automate posts/follows, it only scrapes information off the site. The issue I am finding is that after about 10-15 requests to the TikTok API it requires verification, spouting the following JSON:

```
{
   "code":"10000",
   "from":"",
   "type":"verify",
   "version":"",
   "region":"sg",
   "subtype":"slide",
   "detail":"Hj4wDrDKZhDyu*bE94NlMgd3uQfAXw2eZJGOyoJXO-X9iLbeynU-spQiwbxyOkhJkGKbHNCyGHKuZ4jnJaJfnGedLadLrz8UMPAV*sriWIzRIEwj0PdWEmtZ25SbcEoytp4G631fwjn7y0498dMxisxkA8QnSTTGfswOFlkQBfyyMFYf5TlvDkfxmkjG7qKRHdCOhsnmSLbTCOd6MLcNFJA9WhlmcnhBrJnnVCs-HvoRzOdbpGbOmZ55HjpWIRz0JrQp2EdEjr8-qtQd5jpdpzuXxcfzrLbGFZTjWkyMHPf4vMb3J*q8hIs0zX2gP6IyCsa2et5BQPsB1KU2YyRA5VEvd*8*lZyRR60ZVs46UwtEXAu0l41Y2q0agUrayqnPnj8zpq7H7aK2VS46RZO0W3N7nZ-Jjq4QbAs.",
   "verify_event":"",
   "fp":"verify_kxe9l4xj_3jaJngfM_UEUu_47yj_Au6M_Kp0jwEVrqCJb",
   "scene":"",
   "verify_ticket":"",
   "channel_mobile":"",
   "sms_content":"",
   "mobile":"",
   "email":""
}
```

I am aware of sneaker bots using proxies to avoid these sorts of issues, however TikTok requires cookies authentication from a signed in account so I'm not sure if it will work. Some responses talk about using headless requests, etc., but I've had no luck thus far in preventing this verification process.

Does anyone with experience scraping TikTok have a resolution for this issue?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you scraping the HTML, or are you using TikTok's API?  They probably have monitors that look for scrapers.

Comment: @TimRoberts I am using TikTok's API. I tried using selenium to scrape the HTML however there were too many security measures trying to automate logins, etc.

Comment: OK, so why can't you just re-issue your validation when you get this?

Answer (score -1):

```json
{
  "code": "10000",
  "from": "",
  "type": "verify",
  "version": "",
  "region": "sg",
  "subtype": "slide",
  "detail": "Hj4wDrDKZhDyubE94NlMgd3uQfAXw2eZJGOyoJXO-X9iLbeynU-spQiwbxyOkhJkGKbHNCyGHKuZ4jnJaJfnGedLadLrz8UMPAVsriWIzRIEwj0PdWEmtZ25SbcEoytp4G631fwjn7y0498dMxisxkA8QnSTTGfswOFlkQBfyyMFYf5TlvDkfxmkjG7qKRHdCOhsnmSLbTCOd6MLcNFJA9WhlmcnhBrJnnVCs-HvoRzOdbpGbOmZ55HjpWIRz0JrQp2EdEjr8-qtQd5jpdpzuXxcfzrLbGFZTjWkyMHPf4vMb3Jq8hIs0zX2gP6IyCsa2et5BQPsB1KU2YyRA5VEvd8*lZyRR60ZVs46UwtEXAu0l41Y2q0agUrayqnPnj8zpq7H7aK2VS46RZO0W3N7nZ-Jjq4QbAs.",
  "verify_event": "",
  "fp": "verify_kxe9l4xj_3jaJngfM_UEUu_47yj_Au6M_Kp0jwEVrqCJb",
  "scene": "",
  "verify_ticket": "",
  "channel_mobile": "",
  "sms_content": "",
  "mobile": ""
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).